# PHP Create a Nested Array with indexes from a CSV file

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I'm having a peculiar issue. I have a CSV file that has Comma Separated Values that I need to upload and then get Nested Array of values based on following 3 conditions;

1. The array will first loop through all values and get first 4 unique
   characters. (Codes)
2. Match each column values with the with number of
   columns in each row and give count of rows that matches 4 digit
   codes. (Single_Devices for single column and Dual, Triple and Quad for respective columns count)
3. Match each column values with code and list all the
   columns under the Devices. (Numbers)

**CSV file**

```
123429000000000
123429000000001
123429000000010,123429000000011
123429000000040,123429000000041
```

What I desire is;

```
Array
(
    [Code] => 1234
        (
            [single_devices] => 2
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 123429000000000
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 123429000000001
                        )
                )
            [dual_devices] => 2
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 123429000000010
                            [1] => 123429000000011
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 123429000000040
                            [1] => 123429000000041
                        )
                )
        )

)
```

Is it possible?
I can manage JSON converted data or object or just associative nested array.

**Edit:** This is the code I wrote for which was only showing values and not indexes as I desired.

```
// Get all numbers in array
for ($j = 0; $j < count($csv_file[$i]); $j++){
    $numbers[] = $csv_file[$i][$j];
}

// Get codes from numbers
for ($i = 0; $i < count($csv_file); $i++){
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($csv_file[$i]); $j++){
        $codes[] = substr($csv_file[$i][$j], 0, 4);
    }
}

// Get unique codes from codes array
$codes = array_unique($codes);

// Get numbers and sort them codes and device count wise.
for ($i = 0; $i < count($csv_file); $i++){
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($csv_file[$i]); $j++){
        $q = count($csv_file[$i]); // set device count based on column count
        if (count($csv_file[$i]) == $q){ // if device count is equal to column count
            foreach ($codes as $code){ // loop through unique codes
                if ($code == substr($csv_file[$i][$j], 0, 4)){ // if number's first 4 char matches code
                    // create array with code and then device count and add numbers
                    $devices[$code][$q.'_device_numbers'][$i][$j] = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $csv_file[$i][$j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I am getting from the above code.

```
Array
(
    [1234] => Array
        (
            [1_sim_imeis] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 123429000000000
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 123429000000001
                        )

                )

            [2_sim_imeis] => Array
                (
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 123429000000010
                            [1] => 123429000000011
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 123429000000040
                            [1] => 123429000000041
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: *Is it possible?* - yes, so have a try yourself and add the code to your question.

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how you tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us exactly what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. Give us a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: You need to read line by line, put into an array with explode, count the index numbers then put into an array with your logic. Good luck. When you have a real code we can help you.

Comment: Is it possible for there to be multiple items in the same row, but those items have different starting 4 numbers?

Comment: yes @NigelRen I have edited my question.

Comment: @PatrickQ yes. There will be more rows that will have different starting 4 numbers.

Comment: @Xia  What I mean is, would there ever be a case  where one _single row_ has an entry like `123429000000040,432129000000041`

Comment: @PatrickQ Yes there is a possibility. But we will not be dealing with it yet. :)

Comment: Okay.  Also, your desired output is unclear, and doesn't seem to be the result of an actual `var_dump()`.  Can you show us how the result should look, doing it as if you were hard-coding it?  Meaning write us something like `$result = array("Code" => array( ... ))`.  Or, if the desired result above is in fact the result of some code, please show us the code that is producing that.

Comment: @PatrickQ Please forgive my mistakes. I am new to SO. I have added the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is based on reading the file as a csv (using `fgetcsv()`) and extracting the first 4 digits of the first value on each line.  It then uses another array to give the key for the `'single_devices'` etc. key - using the count of the number of elements on the line (-1 as the array is 0 based)...

```
$fileName = "a.dat";
$output = [];
$baseData = [ 'single_devices', 'dual_devices', 'triple_devices', 'quad_devices' ];
$fh = fopen ( $fileName, "r" );
while ( ($data = fgetcsv($fh)) !== false )  {
    $code = substr($data[0], 0, 4);
    $output[$code][$baseData[count($data)-1]][] = $data;
}

fclose($fh);

print_r($output);
```

which with the test data gives...

```
Array
(
    [1234] => Array
        (
            [single_devices] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 123429000000000
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 123429000000001
                        )

                )

            [dual_devices] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 123429000000010
                            [1] => 123429000000011
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 123429000000040
                            [1] => 123429000000041
                )

        )

)
```

With

```
while ( ($data = fgetcsv($fh)) !== false )  {
    $code = substr($data[0], 0, 4);
    if ( !isset($output[$code]))    {
        $output[$code] = ["code" => $code];
    }
    $deviceLabel = $baseData[count($data)-1];
    $output[$code][$deviceLabel]['count'] =
        ($output[$code][$deviceLabel]['count'] ?? 0) + 1;
    $output[$code][$deviceLabel][] = $data;
}
```

you can get an output of...

```
Array
(
    [1234] => Array
        (
            [code] => 1234
            [single_devices] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 2
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 123429000000000
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 123429000000001
                        )

                )
```

Comment: That is correct. This is what I am currently getting with my code that I already have. But this isn't the desired array I am planning for.

Comment: If you mean you want `[Code] => 1234        (` and `[single_devices] => 2             (`, that isn't a valid array format.  You can add extra fields for them.

Comment: @Xia  That's what I was getting at with my last comment.  The result that you say you want isn't possible.  That's why I was asking for you to show either a result that we _can_ produce, or how you came up with what you're asking for.

Comment: @NigelRen Yes that is somewhat I was aiming for. Ok so it may not be valid array format but as I mentioned that is it possible to get such output in any other way?

Comment: @PatrickQ Yes I edited my answer and added the output I was getting.

Comment: @Xia  I'm not asking for the output that you're getting and _don't_ want.  I'm asking for you to show us how you came up with the result that you say you _do want_.  Or show us an actual hard-coded PHP code equivalent of what you want.

Comment: The last update to my code produces something close to what you seem to want, the `code` and `count` fields contain the data you wanted, but actually in the array rather than as some form of floating data.

Comment: @PatrickQ I'm afraid I do not have any example. That's why I asked if it's possible and if not then what will be more suitable option.

Comment: @NigelRen That is better now. I think I will check that out. I just wanted to return a simple most possible output that I can loop through when I need it else where. =)